# Go web endpoint does not find static index.html file

Tags: go, http, static-files

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const customPort = "3001"

func main() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    port:= fmt.Sprintf(":%s", customPort)
    http.Handle("/", fileServer)

    fmt.Printf("Starting front end service on port %s", port)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

The top level folder is `microservices` and is set up as a go workspace. This web service will be one of many services. It is in the following folder:

```
microservices
 |--frontend
    |--cmd
       |--web
          |--static
             |--index.html
       |--main.go
```

I am in the top level microservices folder, and I am starting it with: `go run ./frontend/cmd/web`. It starts up fine with no errors. But when I go to chrome and type `http://localhost:3001` I get 404 page not found. Even `http://localhost:3001/index.html` gives 404 page not found. I am just learning go and not sure why it is not finding the `./static` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your command the path has to be ./frontend/cmd/web/static, not just ./static. That's not portable; the path changes with the working directory.

Consider [embedding the static directory](https://pkg.go.dev/embed#hdr-File_Systems) instead. Otherwise you'll have to make the path configurable (flag, environment variable, etc.)

The downside with embedding is that you have to rebuild your program after any change to the static files.

You can also use a hybrid approach. If the flag (or whatever) is set, use it to serve from disk, else use the embedded filesystem. The flag is convenient during development and the embedded filesystem makes deployment easy because you only have to copy the program binary.

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "flag"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

//go:embed web/static
var embeddedAssets embed.FS

func main() {
    var staticDir string

    flag.StringVar(&staticDir, "static-dir", staticDir, "Path to directory containing static assets. If empty embedded assets are used.")
    flag.Parse()

    var staticFS fs.FS = embeddedAssets
    if staticDir != "" {
        staticFS = os.DirFS(staticDir)
    }

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFS)))

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! OK yeah... having to put the full path each time is not gonna be portable. Curious: the tutorials i was following actually used go web templates with `{{...}}` syntax. Would that have circumvented this problem? I tried to just do a static html page just to simplify things at the outset. Thx for the embedding tip - will read up on it.

Comment: Templates don't really change anything. You still have to load them by filename. You can embed templates too, of course, so it's the same problem and solution.